# Force iPad/iPhone to use specific location for services

Tags: ios, jailbreak, geolocation

Is there any way to force an iPhone or iPad (jailbroken) to use a different location other then my actual current one. For searching... Say I am in NY, NY and do a search, I want location services to think I am in Miami, FL to give me results from there as if I am in that location.

I've looked under location services. Only obvious things are to turn it on off along with enabled/disabled for other apps.

Answer (score 1):

### [FakeLocation](http://modmyi.com/cydia/com.antoniocalatrava.fakelocation)

> FakeLocation is extremely easy to use. Just open it up, choose the app you want to fake out and then pick your desired fake location, save and you’re done. It’s as simple as that. To end faking your location just un-check the desired app.

### [LocationHolic](http://modmyi.com/cydia/com.sxtb.rwx)

> Fake your iPhone's location with LocationHolic. You can set any location as your iPhones location.

Comment: You should note that both options require a jailbroken phone.

Comment: @Alan The question is about a jailbroken device, tagged [tag:jailbreak] and ‘jailbroken’ mentioned in the question body.